# Database Design: Many tables VS One "long" table _ Performance-Wise?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

Just from a performance point of view:

Store with 10s of 1000s of items with so many categories and attributes. Which is better to store all attributes in one table. Or categorize them in different tables but in this case I'll have to search through all tables for a certain attribute.

Also, What if I used more than one database to store the items. Again, from a performance point of view.

Comment: I don't care about violating normalization rules as long as it's performance efficient

Comment: Assuming all objects are supposed to have same attributes, store them in one table, then use [indexing](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) and other appropriate techniques to achieve optimal performance. If you artificially store such small datasets in separate tables, you might well end-up with _worse_ performance (potentially much worse, depending on what you do). And you should very much care about normalization - if the data is incorrect, it does not matter how quickly you can retrieve it. Therefore, the denormalization for performance's sake should be done very carefully after benchmarking.

Comment: What I did actually is that I divided them into tables with common attributes. For example I had a table about "Mobile Phones" and other for "Laptops" and so on.
But here is the thing, if I want to add for instance "Galaxy S4" in table "Mobile Phones" it'll 've variations "16 or 32GB"also "Black or white" and each combination has its own price, so I'll end up having 4 rows. If I normalized I'll end up having more tables and if I applied norm/ to other categories "Laptops" I'll 've even more. That's why I tried 2 avoid norm/. What do u think?

& thanx for ur answer

Comment: OK, so they do **not** have the same attributes. In that case, you'll have to decide how dynamic your system should be. On the one extreme of the spectrum, you'd have to create a new table for each new set of attributes. On the other extreme, you can use just one table (for common attributes) plus some form of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Answer (score 1):

Databases are designed to store and manage data.  Thousands of rows is considered a "small" table.

You should store all the information about attributes in one table, assuming the attributes are common across all items.  The reasons for using multiple databases would involve security or backup requirements.

If you do get really big tables (say tens of millions of rows) and performance is an issue, then you can start learning about (vertical) partitions.

Comment: Great .. The reason I'm asking is that the website will involve heavy filtrations, that's why I'm concerned about performance. I'm afraid searching through thousands of rows would be an issue with large traffic. And I don't want to do vartical partitioning in the future if it grew big

Comment: @JohnMark . . . You can use indexing to speed things up.